# strange azure sql database connection issue

Tags: sql-server, azure

I got some rather strange sql database connection issue.

We have a VM that is hosted on azure and installed sql server on it.
Randomly it throws

> could not open a connection to SQL Server(53)

However, the exception was not thrown from`conn.Open()`, but from the place I read the Sql Data reader. The problem will last like 5-10 minutes and then disappear for every long time (e.g. days).

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnStr))
{ 
    conn.Open();
    InsrumentName insrument = new InsrumentName();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("WF_CHART_GETNAME", conn))
    {
         SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
         para.Value = code;
         cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (reader.Read())   --------------- Could not open a connection to SQL Server 53 thrown here
         {
            Do something
         }

         return insrument;
    }
}
```

I had a look of the VM and sql server log, but couldn't find anything remotely close. Anyone gets some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a pooled connection is reused, the connection error won't be raised until a query is executed on the connection. `Open` just returns an unused connection from the pool.

Error 53 (gleaned from the command `NET HELPMSG 53`) is "The network path was not found." That suggests a name resolution error which seems to be intermittent in your case.

Next time this happens, try to PING the server from the client using the same name as specified in the connection string.

Comment: oh, that explains at least one big confusion. My connection string actually uses ip address directly "Server=10.19.47.90;Database=XXX;User Id=XXX; password=XXX", so it means that the server with ip address 10.19.47.90 can't be found?

Comment: @daxu, yes. If it was found but not listening on the port, you'll get error 2 instead of 53 after it falls back to named pipes.